# My console logged DOM elements are not shown as elements but as attributes

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I have a very long source code, so I provided the method I am working at the moment below. When I type `console.log(div)` it doesn't render the tree elements. What it renders is in the picture. Why is it doing this?

[Example Picture Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t6JFR.png)

**Method I am working on:**

```js
     playPauseIcons(){



        let tdd = this.table.addRowImage();
        console.log(tdd);
        let img = this.table.getImg();
        console.log(img) 
        console.log(this.table)


        let icondsDiv = document.createElement('div');
        let playDiv = document.createElement('button');
        let pauseDiv = document.createElement('button');
       
        icondsDiv.classList.add('icons_div');
        playDiv.classList.add('play');
        pauseDiv.classList.add('pause');
 
 
                    function animation(){
                    // console.log('pls')
                    img.style.animation =  'car_move 2s ease-in'
 
                    }
 
                    function stopAnimation(){
                     img.style.animation = 'none'
                    }
                        playDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {animation()});
                        pauseDiv.addEventListener('click', () => {stopAnimation()})


        tdd.appendChild(icondsDiv);
        icondsDiv.appendChild(playDiv);
        icondsDiv.appendChild(pauseDiv);
        console.log(icondsDiv)




        let tr = this.table.beginRow()
        tr.appendChild(tdd);
        console.log(tr)
        console.log(tdd)

        console.log('tr from CVC' + tr);

        let tbody = this.table.endRow();
        console.log(tbody)
        console.log(tr)
        tbody.appendChild(tr);
        console.log(tbody)

        tr = null;

     }
```

Comment: There is no `console.log(div)` in the code you have included.

Comment: `console.log('tr from CVC' + tr);` makes no sense, because it implicitly calls `tr.toString`, which is not a useful representation of `HTMLElement`s. Try `console.log('tr from CVC', tr);` instead. In the console output, there are no attributes shown that aren’t shown within tags.

Comment: Why would you expect `console.log(div)` to do something? There's nothing in the code in your question that relates to the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I am new to posting here. I mean when I put some html element so for example console.log(tr) I would expect something like this <tr><td></td></tr>  as I belive had before. But now I get >tr >attributes

Comment: @WandaWix Be precise, please. Are you referring to `<td colspan="4 ">…</td>`? What is the problem with that?

Comment: @SebastianSimon I mean ```td colspan="4"...</td"``` works perfectly as I would imagine.  I am refering to for example ```console.log(tr) ```. In the picture in dev tools its displayed as ```>tr ``` and not like this ```  <tr></tr> ```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mre] and specify your exact browser. This is not reproducible so far.

Comment: The earlier messages were printed when devtools was closed, apparently, hence the difference.